# 2 column comparison using awk script

Tags: awk

I want to compare 2 columns in a file using awk. The columns I want to compare for an expression look like these:
A1 123456 456783 NR A1 789876 432565 NM and so on. I want to separate the 4th and the 8th column from the file which have NR in both the 4th and the 8th columns. 
I have tried using awk `awk '$4 && $8 ~ /NR_/{print}'` but nothing happens when I run the script.
Can someone help.

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell from one sample input line but it sounds like what you want is:

```
awk '($4=="NR") && ($8=="NR")'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question right, Following code will print lines which have NR in their 4th and 8th columns both.

```
awk '$4~"NR"&&$8~"NR" {print}' fileName.txt
```

Comment: When comparing REs (using `~`) use the RE delimiter `/.../` not the string delimiter. You should either be doing a string comparison `$4=="NR"` or a regexp comparison `$4~/NR/` not mixing the constructs. Also, the `{print}` is redundant - that's awks default action when a condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$4 ~ /NR/ && $8 ~ /NR/ ' file
```

Comment: Note that that is testing if $4 **contains** NR, not **is** NR as seems to be what the OP wants from his/her 1 line of sample input. Also, the `{print}` is redundant - that's awks default action when a condition is true.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.